# Aplicação Java Web com Maven com repositório no GitHub e hospedada no OpenShift

Tags: java, maven, github, wildfly, openshift

Tenho uma aplicação Java web (servidor wildfly) criada com o Maven, versionada localmente com Git e remotamente no GitHub, gostaria de saber como faço para hospedar essa aplicação no OpenShift e fazer deploy a cada Pull recebido pelo GitHub.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acredito que seja simples:

1. Entre na sua conta OpenShift
2. Clique em Add application
3. Escolha a versão do Wildfly que deseja usar
4. Na caixa *Source code*, insira a URL do seu repositório Git.

Se fizer isso, o OpenShift diz que fará o seguinte:

> If you provide a Git URL, your application will start with an exact
>   copy of the code and configuration provided in this Git repository.

Acredito então que ele criará uma cópia do seu repositório dentro do OpenShift. Essa cópia terá o comportamento de reiniciar o Wildfly a cada *push* que você fizer.

Nesse caso o *push* deverá ser feito na cópia do OpenShift (que fica em uma outra URL e não a URL do seu repositório Git original).

Não sei se ele mantém os dois repositórios sincronizados. Acredito que não.

Comment: Então no caso eu teria que ter dois repositorios locais, um para fazer _push_ para o _GitHub_ e outro para fazer _push_ para o _OpenShift_?

Comment: Como eu nunca fiz, não posso responder com certeza. Acredito que um dos repositórios locais deixaria de valer e você teria que ficar com o repositório do OpenShift. Um colega diz que o Git suporta um comportamento de "espelhamento" de repositórios, mas não sei como o OpenShift se comporta. O melhor que encontrei para responder essa questão foi [essa pergunta do SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657168/can-i-use-my-existing-git-repo-with-openshift) (em inglês).

Comment: Piovezan esse link do seu comentário é bem esclarecedor, por ele eu preciso ter um único repositório local, mas tenho ele vinculado a dois repositorios remotos, um do _GitHub_ e outro do _OpenShift_, ai faz mais sentido, vou testar e depois dou um feedback.

Comment: seguindo o link indicado por você consegui fazer. Ainda existem alguns ajustes para fazer, mas basicamente é isso. Obrigado.